# frequency sampling filter implementation

Tags: c++, signal-processing

First of all, I'm fairly new to anything related to DSP so my I might be asking something really weird or stupid.

NOTE: the system won't allow me to post mote then to links because I'm too new. I decided to add a - in front of any links so the system won't recognise them as links and I can post them anyway. unfortunately this means you'll have to copy/past to follow the link, sorry about this..

I am currently writing an application that needs control over the entire audible sound spectrum. I have chosen a frequency sampling filter because after reading some information I thought it to be able to give me this sort of control. My implementation consists of a comb filter that feeds 80 resonators in the 0-PI range with a sampling frequency of 44100Hz.

I'm curently getting the following impulse response:
http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/1979/10269409.png

The current frequncy response looks like this:
http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/24/freqj.png

I'm sorry about linking the images in this way, but the system won't allow me to post images because I'm too new, I'm also only allowed 2 links so I'll put a link to the code in a comment if I'm allowed to do that

All my filter coeficients have been 1 in this run

My conclusion is that the resonators are partially canceling eachother out where I wanted each peak to the the same height.
I can't seem to find a way to correct this, is there anyone who can help me?

EDIT 1:
I have put the most important functions here, I should have done that a LOT sooner. I'm happy to clear up anything that might not be clear.

```
//comb filter function
float filter::comb(buffer* x, float z, float input){
    //store the new input value in the buffer
    x->write(input);
    //calculate the output value according to Y[n] = X[n] - z * X[n-160] 
    return x->read(0)-(z*x->read(160));
}

//resonator function
float filter::resonator(buffer* res, float r, float w, float phi, float amp){
static int odd_even=1;
float result=0;

if(odd_even){
    odd_even=0;
    //if called odd times calculate result according to Y[n] = 2 * r * cos(phi) * y[n-1] - r^2 * y[n-1] + amp * w
    result=(2*r*cos(phi)*res->read(0))-(r*r*res->read(1))+(amp*w);
}
else{
    odd_even=1;
    //if called odd times calculate result according to Y[n] = 2 * r * cos(phi) * y[n-1] - r^2 * y[n-1] - amp * w
    result=(2*r*cos(phi)*res->read(0))-(r*r*res->read(1))-(amp*w);
}

//store result in buffer
res->write(result);

return result/SCALE;
}

//filter execute function
float filter::exec(float value){
    float w;
    float total=0;
    float temp=0;

    cout<<value<<"\t";
    //calculate the comb output
    w=comb(combX,0.886867188,value);
    for(int i=0;i<80;i++){
        temp=(resonator(&res[i],0.999,w,(((1.125+i*2.25)/180.0)*pi),getCoef(i)));
        total+=temp;
    }
    return total;
}
```

EDIT 2:

1 resonator at 91.125 degrees:
-http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/9995/42515591.png

I think this is pretty much the desired result, a strong response at the desired frequency

2 resonators at 68.625 and 113.625 degrees: 
-http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6840/3050.png

I think this is close to the desired response too, again strong reactions at the specified frequencies. I think it's a bit odd that the peaks are biger then in the 1 resonator test though.

8 resonators starting at 21.375 and then at 10 degree increments:
-http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/8461/8resonators.png

I'm not sure what to make of this one, the last resonator has an extreme response, but the other ones seem reasonably in line with what should happen.

EDIT 3:
I did another test with 16 resonators:
-http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/8418/68001938.png

This gives pretty much the same result as the 8 resonator test. the major diffrence is that the same efect that is going on near PI is now also starting to get visible near the 0Hz.

Comment: The C++ code is available at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39710897/filter.rar

Comment: You need to do some work to narrow this down to a single specific question - no one here is going to spend time debugging reams of code for you.

Comment: I suppose the basic question is rather simple: does my conclusion (the resonators are canceling eachother out) make sense? If so, what are my options to correct it.

Comment: ok, im confused, you have 160, length 4, float buffers and your exec function passes a new reference every loop so you save the result into the inital position and on the next pass of the loop your using a new reference so the read will always return 0?

Comment: You should test your hypothesis by running one resonator on its own and see if you get the expected impulse response/frequency response. If that's correct then try running two resonators, etc.

Comment: I added some test results (and some code) to the original question

Comment: What are the values that `getCoef()` returns?

Comment: getCoef() returns a float from an array of coeficients. currently all coeficients are 1.0, but they are intended to be able to scale the response that a resonator gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't normalising the resonator gains.  They have different un-normalised gains because as the passband moves closer to 0 or *pi*, the two poles move closer together, so energy injection in the passband begins to excite both poles.

You need to figure out the bandpass gain of each filter (by evaluating its magnitude response at the centre of the passband, via the z-transform), and then divide its output by that.  A quick back-of-envelope calculation gives me the multiplicative normalisation factor to be `(1-r) * sqrt(r^2 - 2.r.cos(2.phi) + 1)`, but please check!

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: how do I apply the normalisation? can I just multiply the resonator output by the normalisation factor?

Comment: @Gurba: Yes, or the input.  Be careful that you don't multiply the things being written back into its buffer, though.

Comment: Thanks!, this seems to get me a long way. It would seem that your suggestion resulted in values around 64 times too small, I'm still busy with checking, finetuning, doublechecking and triplechecking though but it certainly looks good so far

Comment: I think I've got it now, I'll be running some audio trough the filter tonight as a final test as I can't do that now.

Comment: didn't get round to doing the test last night, I'll try to do it tonight

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIR filters as resonators, then they are not linear phase, and it is possible for any overlaps in  the frequency response characteristics to cancel or sum, depending on the phase responses at the overlapping frequency points.

However, as Paul R suggested, you should test each filter individually and then in pairs, to measure the gain of each individual filter, and then check for what happens at the filter cross-over points.

Comment: I'll be running some tests and I'll post the results later on (once I did the tests)

Comment: I added some test results (and some code) to the original question